Using morse theory to construct a deformation retraction
In page 101 of the book: 1984, Barth, Peters,  Van de Ven, Compact  Complex Surfaces, the authors write as follows:

Let $X$ be a complex manifold and $\Delta$ the unit disk in
$\mathbb{C}$.  Let $f: X \rightarrow \Delta$ be a proper
surjective holomorphic map with connected fibers, with only one
singular fibre $X_0$, which is reduced and has no singularities but
ordinary double points.  The pair $(X, X_0)$ is triangulable, so
$X_0$ is a deformation retract of arbitrarily small neighbourhoods in
$X$ (Theorem I.8.8). The function $|f|$ can be used as a
Morse-function on $X \setminus  X_0$. This shows that there is a deformation retraction $\pi: X \rightarrow X_0$.

Recall that a Morse function on a differentiable manifold $M$ is a smooth real-valued function on $M$ such that none of its critical points are degenerate and if $p, q$ are critical, then $f(p) \neq f(q)$.
However, in this post, "with only one singular fibre $X_0$," implies that $f$ itself has no critical point outside $X_0$ (as a complex-valued function).
Consider the real  dimension $d_a$ of the fiber over $a$ with $0<a<1$, we can get that it is $d_a=2n-1$ (where $n$ is the complex dimension of $X$). Then the composition  $X\to \Delta\to \{0\leq x\leq 1\}$ has no critical points on $X\setminus X_0$ (the second arrow is to take the absolute value). So $|f|$ is a "trivial" morse function on $X\setminus X_0$.

Question:  Why is there a deformation retraction $\pi: X \rightarrow X_0$? (i.e., how to use the "trivial" morse function $|f|$  on $X\setminus X_0$ to construct the
precise deformation retraction)


The composition $|f|$, will have critical points only on $X_0$.

@MoisheKohan  Yes, you are right. Thank you. I have revised the question

If I'm reading right, $f$ is identically zero on $X_0$, so "Morse" (on $X$) is presumably meant in the "Bott" sense, and the gradient flow of $|f|$ induces a deformation retraction. <> If that seems reasonable, please write up your own answer.

@AndrewD.Hwang  Could you recommend some references on using Morse functions to produce a deformation retraction?  By the way, I found a more direct method to produce a deformation retraction (from a tubular neighborhood of the fiber), which seems to use the theory of simplicial complexes.  Could you take a look at that post and provide some comments or answers? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4939526/using-the-theory-of-simplicial-complex-to-construct-a-deformation-retraction            Thank you.
