Using the theory of simplicial complex to construct a deformation retraction
Let $X$ be a complex manifold and $Y$ the normal complex analytic space.   Let $f: X \to Y$ be a proper  surjective holomorphic map with connected fibers.
In a paper, the author told us that, for any point $y\in Y$,  by the Lojaziewic's triangulation theorem, we can choose an open Stein neighborhood $U$ such that there is a deformation
retraction $f^{-1}(U)\to X_y:=f^{-1}(y)$.
Question: Why can we choose such $U$ (or how to choose such $U$)?

Clues:
1, The triangulation theorem appears to be as follows:  let $X$ be a complex space and $A$ an analytic subset of $X$. Then
there exists a triangulation of $|X|$ in which $A$ appears as the
support of a sub-complex. In particular, there exists an open
neighbourhood $E$ of $A$ such that $E$ and $\bar{E}$ can be retracted
onto $A$.
2, Consequently, our above question may be reduced to be
a purely algebraically-topologically question: how to use the theory
of simplicial complex to find such $U$ satisfying that there is a
deformation retraction $f^{-1}(U)\to X_y$?

P.S. Note that when $Y$  is   the unit disk in  $\mathbb{C}$,    In page 101 of the book: 1984, Barth, Peters,  Van de Ven, Compact  Complex Surfaces, the authors told us that there is a deformation retraction $X\to X_0$ (However, the method there does not seem to be applicable here.).   For more details, see the post    Using morse theory to construct a deformation retraction

I'm not familiar with "Stein neighborhoods", nor have I seen this precise application of the triangulation theorem. Just some thoughts, then: Triangulate $X$ with $X_y$ a sub-complex. There is an open neighborhood $U'$ (probably the open star of $X_y$) that deformation retracts to $X_y$. Since $X_y$ is connected, so is $U'$ and therefore $f(U')$. It seems likely to me that you can find an open polydisc neighborhood of $f(y)$ inside $f(U')$ from some combination of the restrictions on $f$, which would hopefully be the $U$ you want.

@user176372  Thank you for your ideas.  Since $Y$ is only assumed to be  normal, $f(y)$ may not be a smooth point.  If  $f(y)$ is not  a smooth point, we cannot find a neighborhood of $f(y)$ that is an open polydisc. Hoever,  it doesn't matter.  If we set $Y$ to be smooth, then could you explain that why  we can find a smaller $U$ inside $f(U')$ such that there is a deformation retraction $f^{-1}(U) \rightarrow X_y$?

Maybe I'm a bit optimistic about the preimages here. Perhaps applying the triangulation theorem to the pair $X_y\times {y} \subseteq \text{graph}(f)$ is better.
